# Visual Studio Express 2012 - Silverlight-Enabled WCF Service?

Tags: wcf, entity-framework, silverlight-5.0

I just started a new Silverlight project with Visual Studio Express 2012 for Web.

I created a Silverlight-enabled WCF service to access a SQL Server database, with EF 5.

The problem I'm having is that the service doesn't seem to be able to return any entity retrieved from the database. A new entity or any old object is returned just fine, but when I try to return an entity from the context I get the following exception:

```
{System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: The remote server returned an error: NotFound. --->      System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: NotFound. ---> System.Net.WebException:  The remote server returned an error: NotFound.
   at System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.InternalEndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.<>c__DisplayClassa.<EndGetResponse>b__9(Object sendState)
   at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.<>c__DisplayClass4.<BeginOnUI>b__0(Object sendState)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.BeginOnUI(SendOrPostCallback beginMethod, Object state)
   at System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelAsyncRequest.CompleteGetResponse(IAsyncResult result)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.ServiceModel.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EndCall(String action, Object[] outs, IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.ChannelBase`1.EndInvoke(String methodName, Object[] args, IAsyncResult result)
   at NewProj.DataSvcRef.DataServiceClient.DataServiceClientChannel.EndGetAgency(IAsyncResult result)
   at NewProj.DataSvcRef.DataServiceClient.NewProj.DataSvcRef.DataService.EndGetAgency(IAsyncResult result)
   at NewProj.DataSvcRef.DataServiceClient.OnEndGetAgency(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.OnAsyncCallCompleted(IAsyncResult result)}
```

The service method code couldn't be simpler:

```
[OperationContract]
public Contact GetContact(int aID)
{
  Contact res = null;
  using (var db = new OFBEntities())
  {
    try
    {
      res = db.Contacts.Find(aID);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      res = null;
    }

    return res;
  }
}
```

As I mentioned, if I return a newly created object (*return new Contact(){ name="test contact};*), or return a type that is not in context (say an integer for example), everything works fine.

Is this a limitation of the express version, or am I forgetting some settings? In the past I have created some Silverlight apps that consumed data services with VS 2010, Silverlight 4, and I don't remember having to set anything special, but maybe I just forgot that I did?

Any help is appreciated!

**EDIT:**
Could it have anything to do with DbContext and the way it is serialized? I've never used DbContext before, I always used the default ObjectContext in EF 4...

**EDIT2: SOLUTION**
It's been a while, but I had other things to work :o)
In case anybody is in the same boat, the problem was in the serialization by the service. DbContext by default creates proxies, which don't agree with serialization. I am not sure why yet - indeed, I need to educate myself about those proxies - but disabling them solves my serialization issue.
Thanks for the comment Pawel, I mistakenly thought my serialization was going OK, rechecking the server-side error put me back on the right track.

Comment: Are you sure your service is running at all?

Comment: I'm sure :o) as I said, the service is called, I can step through it, and it returns as expected if the return value doesn't come from a context. Could it be because the EF 5 now defaults to DbContext - my previous experience was with EF 4, which only had ObjectContext at the time?

Comment: I don't see anything related to Entity Framework in the stack trace. I am not a WCF guru but it appears to me that the stack trace you are showing is from the client side while the exception is happening on the server side. If you show the exception/stack trace from the server side it should be easier to figure out what's going on. To add to your edit - if proxies are enabled it may be impossible to serialize entities since they have a reference to an object that is not serializable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with automatic proxy creation by the DBContext, which interfered with the serialization.
Proxies are on by default in DBContext, you can disable them in the class constructor

```
  this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
```

or after creating an instance of your DBContext

```
  using (var db = new myDBContext())
  {
    db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;

    ...
  }
```

Not sure why yet, but it works. Time to go read up on that!